# Heatmap.js with GMaps - Display and Hide individual datapoints

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, heatmap

I don't use JavaScript very much. I'd like to display and hide individual datapoints on my heatmap based on a UI slider and the code below works but is inefficient due to having to loop through a list every time.

It's ok for small test datasets but not scalable. Anyone have ideas on how to show and hide individual datapoints specifically for a **heatmap on Google Maps?**

This is my working code.

When slider moved, loop through individual data points for journey.

```
for (var i = 0; i < listOfJourneys.length; i++) {

   for (var j = 0; j < listOfJourneys[i]['listOfJourneyDataPoints'].length; j++) {
```

Get time of current journey datapoint

```
      var journeyTime = listOfJourneys[i]['listOfJourneyDataPoints'][j]['Seconds'];

      var currentTime = new Date(parseInt(journeyTime.substring(6, (time.journeyTime -2))));
```

if current data point outside the 'to' and 'from' slider boundaries then hide (i.e., remove) data point.

```
      if (currentTime >= slider_min_val && currentTime <= slider_from || currentTime >= slider_to && currentTime <= slider_max_val) {

        displayedDataPoints[i]['listOfJourneyDataPoints'][j] = "";
  }
```

Otherwise, if the datapoint is not outside 'to' and 'from' slider boundaries, and datapoint is already hidden, then display data point (i.e., clone object from original data.)

```
      else {

        if (displayedDataPoints[i]['Journey'][j] === "") {

                 displayedDataPoints[i]['listOfJourneyDataPoints'][j] =
JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(originalListOfJourneys[i]['listOfJourneyDataPoints'][j]));

              }                  

            }
```

Set data points on the map.

```
        heatmap.setData(getAllPoints(currentTripList));

    }

 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do the journeys matter on the output?  Or just the data points?
I'm thinking just combine all of the journey datapoints into a single array.  Sort this by time.
Then you just need to know the first/last index in that array when the slider moves to take a slice out of the array.
You could event pre-calculate these indexes if your slider has a fixed granularity (hours?)